# How do you add methods to a javascript object and use the object's variables

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods

I want to be able to use an object's member variables:

```
function Upload(file, filename, id){
    this.file=file
    this.filename=filename
    this.id=id;
};

Upload.prototype.displayImage = function(btn){
    $.canvasResize(file,
        {
            width: 160,
            height: 0,
            crop: false,
            quality: 100,
            callback: function (data)
        {
            $('#'+btn).css("background", "url("+data+")")
        }
    });
};
```

I access the object and method like this:

```
var upload = new Upload(frontPic, frontPicName, id);
  upload.displayImage("btnFrontUploadShow");
```

However I am getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: file is not defined
$.canvasResize(file,
```

Why can't I use the `file` variable in the displayImage method, and how can I declare displayImage so that the `file` variable is available for use?

Comment: You want to use `this.file`

Comment: More generally, all instance variables need to be accessed as `this.something`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to distinguish between variables and properties. The three parameters of your constructor function (`file, filename, id`) are [local] *variables* to that function, and cannot be accessed from outside.

Yet, you created *properties* (with the same names) on your instance (referenced via the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) by assigning them the values. In the prototype method, you can only access these properties, and so you will need to use the dot member operator for them - variables with that name are not defined in the function's scope (as the exception message clearly states). Use `this.file` instead.

Answer (score 2):

To access any property on an Object just use:

```
this.file
this.id
this.{nameOfProperty}
```

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way to “declare” it so that it can be used in all prototype methods — you have to use `this.file` instead of `file`.

The alternative would be not to use a prototype method:

```
function Upload(file, filename, id) {
    this.file = file;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.id = id;

    this.displayImage = function(btn) {
        $.canvasResize(file,
            {
                width: 160,
                height: 0,
                crop: false,
                quality: 100,
                callback: function(data)
                {
                    $('#' + btn).css("background", "url(" + data + ")")
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
```